# Django serializer ManyRelatedManager object at XX is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I'm trying to use a ModelSerializer for a Model that has a Many to Many field.

This is part of my model:

```
class BaseSearchService(models.Model):

advertisements = models.ManyToManyField(Advertisement, null=False,
    blank=False)
```

And this is the serializer

```
class SearchTransportSickPersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

person = TransportPersonComponentSerializer()
owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
advertisements = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

class Meta:
    model = SearchTransportSickPerson
    fields = ('name', 'description',
        'date_service_full_day', 'date_service', 'origin_lat',
        'origin_long', 'destinity_lat', 'destinity_long', 'multiple_stops',
        'person', 'owner', 'advertisements')

def create(self, validated_data):

    user_data = validated_data.pop('owner')
    advs = validated_data.pop('advertisements')

    user = User.objects.get(email=user_data.email)

    person_data = self.validated_data.pop('person')
    person = TransportPersonComponent.objects.create(**person_data)

    sickPerson = SearchTransportSickPerson.objects.create(person=person,
        owner=user, **self.validated_data)

    for adv in advs:
        a = Advertisement.objects.get(id=adv.id)
        sickPerson.advertisements.add(a)

    sickPerson.save()

    return sickPerson
```

I have writen a unit test that replicates the error:

```
def test_serializer_2(self):
    transportSickPerson = SearchTransportSickPerson(name="name",
        description="desc", date_service=date_serv, date_service_full_day=
        True, person=self.component, owner=self.user)

    transportSickPerson.save()

    transportSickPerson.advertisements.add(advertise)

    serializer = SearchTransportSickPersonSerializer(transportSickPerson)
    content = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

When I try to render the serializer with the JSON Renderer, the following error gets thrown:

TypeError: .ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7f648017bfd0> is not JSON serializable

And when i print the serializer data, the dict type has the advertisements field as the ManyRelatedManager representation.

How can i solve this error? Is there any way to tell the serializer how to render that specific field?

Thank you for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: The answer is `class.property.all()`.

---

The problem here lies in the fact that a `ManyRelatedManager` is NOT the actual list of related objects, but a Django class from which you have to call `all()` (or `filter()` or `get()`) in order to get to your data. Trying to serialize the related manager makes no sense.

Look at this example:

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

if I have an instance of `SomeClass` called `some_class`, calling `some_class.friends` will return:

```
<RelatedManager>
```

while `some_class.friends.all()` will return

```
[<User>, <User>, ecc]
```

---

Side note:

you should **not** use `null=False` on `ManyToManyField`: it is useless. As you already know, when you create a new `BaseSearchService` your `advertisements` field is empty (thus, demonstrating that null=False serves no purpose). This is because, at database level, M2M fields are not a column in your `BaseSearchService` table but a table in itself.

Every time you call `.add()` (or any other manager methods like `.remove()`) a call to the database is made, independently from the `.save()` method of the model instance on which there is the M2M field. In other words, no need to call `sickPerson.save()` also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So should i pass the friends list to the serializer not into a Someclass instance but as another serializer field?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've finished implementing the desired solution!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! :) If you haven't already done that, I suggest you read this page carefully if you want to proceed developing with Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/

Comment: It didn't really help. we all know it's not serialize. Not providing a solution and just telling it's not possible is not a real solution..

Comment: The solution is literally shown 2 times in my answer. It would have taken you less time to read it throughly than the time it took you to write your comment.

Comment: if you could highlight or make, `you should **not** use null=false` not as bold. would be a clear impression.